# Libcurl doesnt work when i compile as dll

Tags: c, windows, libcurl

I have this code working exactly as intended.

```
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <openssl/ssl.h>
    #include <curl/curl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void func();
}

    
    //FILE * myFile = fopen("min.exe", "wb");
    size_t writefunction(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
    {
      
      printf("called.. writeFunction\r\n");
      //fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, myFile);
      fclose(myFile);
      return (nmemb*size);
    }

void func(){
    CURL *ch;
          CURLcode rv;
          char caPath[128];
          char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

          rv = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
          ch = curl_easy_init();


          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://someapp.herokuapp.com/");

         /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
           /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);

          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, *writefunction);
          //rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

          printf("set Up CA Path..\r\n");
          //memset(caPath,'0',sizeof(caPath));
         // strcpy(caPath,"/home/test/SSL_Server");
          rv = curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH,caPath);
        
                      printf("set Up CA Path..\r\n");

        
          rv = curl_easy_perform(ch);
          printf("curl easy perform done..\r\n");

          if(rv == CURLE_OK){
            printf("*** transfer succeeded ***\n");
            
            //return 0;
          }else
          {
             printf("*** transfer failed..****\n");
             perror("failed:");
            //return 0;
                   /* if the request did not complete correctly, show the error
  information. if no detailed error information was written to errbuf
  show the more generic information from curl_easy_strerror instead.
  */
    size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", rv);
    if(len)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
              ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(rv));
     }


}


int main(void)
{
 func();
}
```

if I change this part

```
int main(void)
{
 func();
}
```

to dll

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
      func();
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    {
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

the programs waits or crashes at `curl_easy_perform()` i use gcc and i include `-lcurl` in all my compilation.

Why doesnt it work as a dll?

Comment: Time to crack out your debugger and find out more about this bug.

Comment: See [DLL Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices#general-best-practices) for what you can, and especially can *not*, do in `DllMain`.

Comment: check `__cdecl` / `__stdcall` and this stuff

Comment: yes it works with exported function but not from dllmain. i'll see, it'd be more useful for us inside dllmain.

Comment: From @dxiv link: `[Not] Use the memory management function from the dynamic C Run-Time (CRT). If the CRT DLL is not initialized, calls to these functions can cause the process to crash.`